# Make a site hosted in IIS server use https and access it within the intranet

Tags: ssl, certificate, https, iis, intranet

I have a site hosted on my IIS server and I can access it on `http:localhost`. I made a self-signed certificate and added it to the site and can access it via `https:\\localhost`. I want the site to be accessible to other devices in the same network but I want the https version of it. What can be done in order to achieve this ? What are the possible solutions to this ?

One solution I thought of was using the IP address of the hosted machine
for example: `https:\\176.16.5.136` , but using a self signed certificate could resolve this or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Here are the steps I did :

1. Generated self signed certificate
2. Import it to the Root CA
3. When I view the certificate it says "This certificate is ok".
4. Bind it to the local site on IIS server on port 443 for https

IIS Binding:

[image: Binding]

Output:

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you post the actual certificate in PEM format?

Comment: @u1686_grawity i am using following commands to generate the certificate :
# Generate self-signed certificate
        $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "$ipAddress" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\\LocalMachine\\My" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(20) -Type SSLServerAuthentication

Comment: Right, and $ipAddress is **not a DNS name.** Certificates have two distinct "name types" for domain names vs IP addresses, and I'm about 80% sure that this is the problem.

Comment: @u1686_grawity there might be multiple websites on the IIS server, I want to particularly redirect the traffic within the intranet to go to the website I want it to go to, for that reason I am trying to generate the certificate for the IP Address and binding it within the website say test.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that `https:\\192.168.1.4` won't work over the LAN.
You might need to allow port `443` in your server's firewall.

Using a self signed certificate might cause a problem with some browsers,
but this can usually be forced through.

See for example
[IIS Configuration - Set up HTTPS Binding for port 443](https://www.ge.com/digital/documentation/opshub/windows/windows/t_oh_webspace_configureIIS.html).

Comment: I tried the method it did not work, one thing here is that i have generated the certificate for my local ip address, can it be causing the issue. I have updated the question as well if you could check it.

Comment: Follow the method in my link.

Comment: yes that did not work, one thing i would like to put here is that the website when binded to localhost i.e `https:\\localhost` works fine but not for the IP address

Comment: That's natural - a certificate is set to authenticate only one CN with at most wildcards. Do this: `ping -4 google.com` which gives IP `216.58.215.46`. Now try in a browser `https://216.58.215.46/`.

Comment: is there a work around so that i can make the hosted site accessible on the intranet ?

Comment: You can't do that from within IIS - you'll need to generate the certificate using OPENSSL. See [Self Signed SSL/TLS Certificate with IP Address](https://nodeployfriday.com/posts/self-signed-cert/).

Answer (score 0):

Certificates have *distinct types* for "DNS domain" names and "IP address" names. When creating a certificate, you have to correctly specify the type because browsers actually pay attention to that, and the very confusing error message in your screenshot comes from the fact that even though the 'name' is correct (i.e. it matches the URL), it is rejected due to being marked as the wrong type (because of the `-DnsName` option being used).

Unfortunately, PowerShell doesn't seem to have an `-IpAddress` option or anything similar.

While there are ways to create such certificates in CLI (certutil, openssl), I would *probably* suggest using [XCA](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/) for that purpose. (See the video on its webpage at around 2:20 where the "subject alternative names" are being added – note the list of name types.)

(In fact, I'd suggest using XCA to create an *actual CA* rather than a bunch of individual self-signed TLS certificates. Having your own CA means that your users will only ever need to install the single CA certificate and not every single TLS certificate that you might end up creating.)

Even better would be to have an actual domain name for the website – either an internal domain as many corporations have, or a real Internet domain that merely points to an internal IP address.

Comment: I get it, but instead of using the commands and using the IIS `create self signed certificate` feature I was able to access it locally but not over the intranet , i,e on other devices such as mobile phones or laptop connected on the same internet.